# How can I send an automated email to pending members after they complete the registration form?

Tags: forms, email, automation

I manually approve/validate member applications, so I don't need a member activation key email. What I am looking for is an automated email that pending members receive after submitting the registration form that tells them that we have received their info and that they will be approved shortly. I'm not very familiar with EE yet, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a free add-on that does just that: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/registration-emails